# Select all records from table a. table b has complementary data but only one record matches table a. I need all of them

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL database with 2 tables:

```
Table A:
id     name   age
123a   John   34
143w   Mark   27
143x   Rony   30

Table B:
id     company     job
143w   Google      developer


I need:
id     name   age  company  job
123a   John   34
143w   Mark   27   Google   developer
143x   Rony   30
```

I need a select statement that can extract the result above.
Thanks in advance
Paulo

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` on `id`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried that. I tested that one already but for records on A that have no corresponding records on B instead, fields that should be empty get the content of other records. in my model case above running a LEFT JOIN statement I would get: For id=123a name=John age=34 company=Google job=developer and the same happens to id=143x when company and job for those two should be blank. Something is still missing. Thanks

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce54c9/3 shows a left join giving the results you want. You might want to `COALESCE` the `NULL` values into empty strings e.g. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce54c9/4

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've got it working the way I need with the left join. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

from the requirements that you need, i assume you need this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
```

Comment: Dear Fachry, thanks, but there is a problem. I tested your sugestion but for records on A that have no corresponding records on B instead on blank fields the get the content of other records. in my model case above running your SELECT statement I would get: For id=123a   name=John   age=34 company=Google   job=developer and the same happens to id=143x when company and job for those two should be blank. Something is still missing. Thanks